# Access static variable in synchronized block

Tags: java, synchronization

(Java synchronization problem)As my title, can I access a static variable in a synchronized block? Will it cause inconsistency ? Can anyone tell me the detail of the disadvantages or advantages of accessing a static variable synchronized block.

Comment: *can I access a static variable in a synchronized block?*..Try that . *Will it cause inconsistency?* What makes you to think so?

Comment: If you have a static variable the synchronization should be realized through  a static method of the object that holds such variable or by  using a synchronized block with synchronization on the class of the object that holds that variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*can I access a static variable in a synchronized block ?*

Yes, You can.

*Will it cause inconsistency ?*

Static means shared across all the instances of that Class in a JVM. Shared resources are **not thread-safe**.Hence Static variables are not thread safe.So, if multiple threads tries to access a static variable, it may result in inconsistency.

The ways, which I know of to synchronize access to a static variable.

1. Synchronize on Static object.

   ```
      public class SomeClass{
         private static int sum = 0;
         private static final Object locker = new Object();

         public void increaseSum() {
              synchronized (locker) {
              sum++;
         }
       }
     }
   ```
2. Synchronized Static method.

   ```
   public class SomeClass {
       private static int sum = 0;

      public static synchronized void increaseSum() {
        sum++;
    }
   }
   ```
3. Synchronize on class object

   ```
    public class SomeClass {
       private static int sum= 0;

       public void increaseSum() {
          synchronized (SomeClass .class) {
          sum++;
        }
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: What if the static variable is a public variable used in different classes in the same application. Will there be any inconsistencies?

Comment: Of course, there are chances for inconsistencies if there are multiple threads executing code in different classes simultaneously which are trying to modify/read a common variable.