# Correct way to Synchronize Methods in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a sample class:

```
public class LocksAndSynchronization {

    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();

    static int count;

    public void methodOne() {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
            count++;
        }

    }

    public void methodTwo() {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
            count++;
        }

    }

    public synchronized void process() {
        methodOne();
        methodTwo();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final LocksAndSynchronization l = new LocksAndSynchronization();
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                l.process();
            }

        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                l.process();
            }

        };


        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();


        System.out.println("count: " + count);

    }

}
```

**process()** actually makes a call to both the methods. So which is a better approach?

1. Synchronize `methodOne` and `methodTwo`  or,
2. Synchronize `process()` (as done in the code above) ?

Both of the above options would work. But which of them makes more sense?

Comment: For this particular problem, you could dispense with `static` `int` and use `static` `volatile` `AtomicInteger`.  It would free you from having to lock at all and possibly improve performance.  A reasonable goal is to use as little locking as you need (while using that which is required to protect access to mutable state).

Answer (score 3):

count is static, so it is same for all object. so you need to syncronize process static way. to do that, create a static lock and use it

```
static Object staticObject = new Object();
public void process() {
   synchronized( staticObject){
      methodOne();
      methodTwo();
   }
}
```

or you can synronize methodOne and methodTwo

```
static Object staticObject = new Object();
public void methodOne() {
    synchronized( staticObject){
      for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
          count++;
      }
    }
}

public void methodTwo() {
    synchronized( staticObject){
      for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
          count++;
      }
    }
}
```

moreover, using synchronize keyword in function declaration, it means using object itself as lock. so, if you have multiple object, you block is synchronized according to object.

Comment: Keep in mind that the method code is just a simple example of actual code. I think OP  got inadvertently involved in this static/non-static detail.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you really made me think. I didn't quite understood the static/non-static rule here. 
Is there a rule or contract in synchronization related to this?

Comment: It's simple: `count` is effectively a global variable, and your locking scheme will allow two different instances of `LocksAndSynchronization` to independently enter the synchronized blocks, resulting in a data race on `count`. `LocksAndSynchronization` may be a singleton and then this wouldn't be an issue; however then there would also be no point in using a static to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to synchronize `methodOne` and `methodTwo` since they may be called from outside the object. They also can be called without being embedded in `process`. Therefore each method should be implemented in a threadsafe manner on its own.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Your simplified code doesn't make it easy to discern the essence of your question. For one, `count` is static so locking at instance level can't work, but that could just be a distractor.

A more important consideration are `methodOne` and `methodTwo`, two *public* methods which apparently require synchronization, but do none on their own. If you choose to synchronize just the `process` method, that means that you are requiring all the other callers of `methodOne` and `methodTwo` to take proper care of synchronization as well, which looks like quite shaky design.

Moreover, if you don't need the entire `process` to be atomic, and it can decompose into two separate atomic steps, then again it is more natural to have locking follow those semantics. This depends on whether you'll be calling `methodOne` and `methodTwo` from aynwhere else in your program.

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to synchronize as little piece of code as possible, because it generates contentions (other threads waiting). Therefore approach no 1 is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

No matter whether you synchronize `process` or any of the methods separately, you still will not have consistency between method1 and method2 (i.e. that the variable `count` would not be changed between these calls). The reason is that the variable `count` is static, so it's not thread-safe even though it's used from within a `synchronized` method.

Comment: so that means count will not have a consistent value on output?

Comment: In theory, it might. There is an answer outlining that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263888/access-static-variable-in-synchronized-block

Comment: the code is working perfectly fine (count is consistently 40000)

Comment: Perhaps it's because you don't have any other thread accessing this variable? In that case, there should not be any problems.

Comment: :| I already have 2 threads accessing the variable. That should prove, if there was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Adem says, the static 'count' field needs a static lock. However there is a bigger interface design concern here. Both `methodOne` and `methodTwo` are *public* meaning that that they can be called from any other class. If they are required to execute in a synchronised context then it's advisable that they both utilise the synchronisation mechanism.

If it were not the case that `methodOne` and `methodTwo` were public, my preference would be to perform the syncrhonisation at the higher level (because this is slightly more efficient and flexible), i.e. in the `process` method, and then to put a comment on the other two methods which specifies that they must be called from a synchronized context.